# Convert a record with comma separated values into a set

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string with multiple records. Each record has a varying list of words separated by commas. I want to convert each record into a set where the words in a record are the values in the set. Can you please advise on how to convert it to a set?

E.g. below are the two records in a file.

```
citrus fruit,semi-finished bread,margarine,ready soups
tropical fruit,yogurt,coffee
```

I would like to convert them to :

```
{'citrus fruit','semi-finished bread','margarine','ready soups'}
{'tropical fruit','yogurt','coffee'}
```

Comment: Do you actually want a `set` or a `list`? A `set` is an unordered collection with no duplicates. A `list` is ordered and may contain duplicates.

Comment: How are the records delimited?

Comment: records are delimited by a new line character. Need a set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not convinced you want a `set`, since in your example you're listing everything in order in your desired result. `set`s are unordered, and cannot contain duplicates. It's also not clear how your records are delimited.

Here's an example that will maintain order, using `list`:

```
>>> first_record = "citrus fruit,semi-finished bread,margarine,ready soups"
>>> second_record = "tropical fruit,yogurt,coffee"
>>> def tokenize(s, delim=","):
...   return s.split(delim)
... 
>>> first_result = tokenize(first_record)
>>> first_result
['citrus fruit', 'semi-finished bread', 'margarine', 'ready soups']
>>> second_result = tokenize(second_record)
>>> second_result
['tropical fruit', 'yogurt', 'coffee']
```

and if you really want a `set`, just wrap it in a call to the `set` constructor:

```
>>> first_result_set = set(first_result)
>>> second_result_set = set(second_result)
>>> first_result_set
{'margarine', 'ready soups', 'semi-finished bread', 'citrus fruit'}
>>> second_result_set
{'coffee', 'yogurt', 'tropical fruit'}
```

EDIT: You can do it all in one shebang since we know the records are delimited by newline:

```
>>> records = "citrus fruit,semi-finished bread,margarine,ready soups\ntropical fruit,yogurt,coffee"
>>> def setitize_records(records, record_delim="\n", item_delim=","):
...   record_list = records.split(record_delim)
...   record_sets = [set(record.split(",")) for record in record_list]
...   return record_sets
... 
>>> result = setitize_records(records)
>>> result
[{'margarine', 'ready soups', 'semi-finished bread', 'citrus fruit'}, {'coffee', 'yogurt', 'tropical fruit'}]
```

Comment: @aseempuri Awesome! Mind upvoting too if you found the snippet useful?

Answer (score 0):

Use the csv module.

```
import csv

def readsets(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for row in csv.reader(f):
            yield set(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. check it out.

```
rec = "citrus fruit,semi-finished bread,margarine,ready soups tropical
fruit,yogurt,coffee"
#result 
myset = set() 

while rec != "":
    head, _ , rec = rec.partition(',')
    myset.add(head)
print(myset)
```